# How to enable hardware virtualization on MacBook Pro 2020 M1?

Tags: macos, virtualization, virtualbox, apple-silicon

I just got a new MacBook Pro 2020 M1.

I installed the VirtualBox and tried to create a new VM to install Windows but is show me an error that says: "System Acceleration Settings: The hardware virtualization is enabled in the Acceleration section of the system although it is not supported from the host system. It should be disabled in order to start the visual system.".

I'am going to the Settings, System, Acceleration and there when i try to untick the box "hardware virtualization" it doesnt let me, so I probably have to enable in the host system but I don't know where I can do it.

The VM is off so that wouldn't be the problem.

Can someone help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to enable virtualization on M1 - the hardware is capable of running these workloads out of the box. [VirtualBox doesn’t run on Apple Silicon.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/430239/5472)

What is needed is selecting software that is built for M1 and takes advantage of the system capabilities - either with full native code support or using Rosetta2 to cross compile Intel code and libraries.

A far too brief list of options is below (and over time these will likely need editing)

- Parallels - yes - Includes [Windows 11 official support from Microsoft and Parallels](https://kb.parallels.com/125375/)
- qemu - yes
- VMware - mostly
- VirtualBox - no

Depending on which virtualization stack and guest OS (windows or a flavor of unix perhaps) that  you choose, you may need to select ARM specific guest OS to run on the Apple Silicon host system hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Finally after a few day's I find a way to install windows on M1 Mac.
I find a website that tells you step by step how to do it.

If u are interested on that there is a link for the Website below.

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/success-virtualize-windows-10-for-arm-on-m1-with-alexander-grafs-qemu-hypervisor-patch.2272354/

Comment: Note that is windows arm whiff h does not run most windows programs

Comment: Now win arm runs any 32-Bit win program through emulation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no virtualization of Windows for Intel on an ARM based Mac.  The usual suspects like VMWare and Parallels have announced products.  As I post this Parallels has a product available for ARM Macs but not VMWare.

https://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/resources/#sysreq

https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/faq.html#virtual

I see an answer posted already about QEMU as an option.

Answer (score -1):

One way to run hardware virtualization with M1 chip is to enable virtualization through a container, e.g. Docker.

See Docker's official documentation, docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon

For example, Fedora Linux distro .iso live image can run as an instance virtualized in a Docker container, developer.fedoraproject.org/tools/docker/docker-usage.html

Answer (score -1):

Addressing the question about virtualization... I don't know re virtualization support, but my deep research this week shows that M1 Macs have several options for VMs.

Myself I'm about to setup an M1 MBA for pentesting. Here's what I've found:

1. Parallels supposedly handles Win 11 and Kali Linux out of the box.
2. VMWare works (but has some problems) with both OSes.
3. UTM is a free option that also handles both of those OSes.
4. VirtualBox announced a V7 developer preview that runs on Arm64 M1/M2 hosts.

I'm about to try some of these at least, so I haven't much more to say just yet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How is your comment any more help to me? A fine example of why I hate StackExchange so much. My answer isn't that different than another comment here, so why are you picking on me? My intent is pure, and I DID ADD TO THE CONVERSATION!!

Comment: Perhaps your experience on SE isn’t as positive as it could be is because there’s a disconnect with the model.  This is a Q&A site and answers are for posts that directly answer the question.  This isn’t a forum  where a “conversation” takes place. It might help you to take the [tour] to maximize your experience here.

Comment: I’ve reviewed the other four answers; while a couple are very low quality and (IMO) quite incorrect, they are in fact answers.  They can be wrong and will likely he voted down, but they are answers nonetheless.  Your initial answer was “there is software, wait and see” (a comment) to now repeating what has already been posted.  Remember the question is “How to enable HW virtualization on M1”