# Is it possible to run Chrome Browser in a virtual machine on macOS?

Tags: macos, virtualization, web-browser

I have a new M1 Mac running Ventura. I personally prefer using Firefox, and I use Safari as a backup. However, I need to test a few things on Chrome.

I am really reluctant to install Chrome, or any Google product for that matter. I did install it but I don’t like the fact that it’s always doing something in the background so I uninstalled it.

Is there a way to get Chrome running in a virtual machine which I can fire up only when I need it?

Comment: There are several VMs that can run on Apple and they run Linux or Windows - is that what you are after. Just search for virtual machine here.

Comment: @mmmmmm Thanks for the comment. I was wondering about running macOS Chrome, not Linux or Windows. Also, some of them have started to falter on M1.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/422566/237 for the current state of VMs on Apple Silicon - if you know more please comment. Parallels can run macOS

Answer (score 1):

On an M1 running Ventura, you can install a macOS VM. It takes a few steps though, see The Eclectic Light Company's article [Building and using a macOS 13.1 VM on Apple silicon](https://eclecticlight.co/2022/12/15/building-and-using-a-macos-13-1-vm-on-apple-silicon/).