# How to install linux guest OS on Apple M2 silicon (Ventura OS)?

Tags: virtualization, ventura, virtualbox, apple-silicon

I have a 2023 Macbook Pro with Apple M2 silicon. I am trying to install Debian 11 as a guest OS, but keep getting the error that "No bootable medium is found." I am mounting the arm64 .iso of Debian found [here](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/arm64/iso-cd/). This is happening with every OS I try to install on VirtualBox (Ubuntu Server, Fedora, Debian).

**Edits**

- [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422565/does-virtualbox-run-on-apple-silicon) asks about M1 silicon, my question is about the new M2 silicon, therefore this question is not a duplicate
- I do have the developer preview of VirtualBox installed

[image]

Comment: The issue is as VirtualBox home page starts "VirtualBox is a powerful x86 and AMD64/Intel64 virtualization product" It does not run on Apple Silicon. There is a developer preview but better to use another VM.

Comment: Did you download the Developer Preview for ARM/Apple Silicon Macs?  https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: @Allan yes I have the beta developer preview

Comment: In this case the answer is for Apple Silicon as a whole so both m1 and m2